# Bold font in h1, h2, h3 titles - 92590

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help in finding out how to get a bold font in Elegant theme in WordPress, but only in the heading areas (h1, h2, h3 etc), since I have no problem getting it in the text body.

I've tried, even though in the editor I'm getting bold headings, it's not the case once I publish the page, no matter what changes I make.

I'm including the code (not full but the part that matters) - none of the changes in 'h1' area are reflected once published, not even the font type, except the size. I'm not a coder so maybe there's something I'm missing. Please, help:

```
/*------------------------------------------------*/

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; }

body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
blockquote, q { quotes: none; }


blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus { outline: 0; }

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins { text-decoration: none; }
del { text-decoration: line-through; }

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }


/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[BASIC STYLES]-----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

body { line-height: 18px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: black; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; background-color: #15191f; }

a { text-decoration: none; color: #00b7f3; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.clear { clear: both; }
.ui-tabs-hide { display: none; }
br.clear { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { padding-bottom: 5px; color: #111; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1em; font-weight: bold; }
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: #111; }
h1 { font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
h2 { font-size: 24px; }
h3 { font-size: 22px; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; }
h6 { font-size: 14px; }
p { padding-bottom: 10px; line-height: 18px; }
strong { font-weight: bold; color: #1c1c1c; }
cite, em, i { font-style: italic; }
pre, code { font-family: Courier New, monospace; margin-bottom: 10px; }
ins { text-decoration: none; }
sup, sub { height: 0; line-height: 1; position: relative; vertical-align: baseline; }
sup { bottom: 0.8em; }
sub { top: 0.3em; }
dl { margin: 0 0 1.5em 0; }
dl dt { font-weight: bold; }
dd  { margin-left: 1.5em;}
blockquote  { margin: 1.5em; padding: 1em; color: #666666; background: #e6e6e6; font-style: italic; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }
    blockquote p { padding-bottom: 0px; }

input[type=text],input.text, input.title, textarea, select { background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #bbb; padding: 2px; color: #4e4e4e; }
input[type=text]:focus, input.text:focus, input.title:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus { border-color:#2D3940; color: #3e3e3e; }
input[type=text], input.text, input.title, textarea, select { margin:0.5em 0; }
textarea { padding: 4px; }

img#about-image { float: left; margin: 3px 8px 8px 0px; }

.clearfix:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------[MAIN LAYOUT INFO]---------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

#top { background: url(images/top-bg.png) repeat-x; }
    #top-wrapper { background: url(images/top-wrapper-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center; }
        #top-content { background: url(images/top-content-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; }
            #bottom-light { background: url(images/bottom-light-bg.png) no-repeat bottom center; }
                .container { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; position: relative; }
                    #top .container { padding-bottom: 60px; } 
                        #logo { margin: 65px 13px 35px; }
                        #menu { background: url(images/left-menu-bg.png) no-repeat top left; padding-left: 11px; height: 49px; }
                            #menu-right { background: url(images/right-menu-bg.png) no-repeat top right; padding-right: 11px; height: 49px; }
                                #menu-content { background: url(images/content-menu-bg.png) repeat-x; height: 49px; }
                        #social-icons { float: right; margin-right:23px; margin-top: 17px; }
                            #social-icons a { padding-left:4px; }       

#content { background: url(images/content-bg.png); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; } 
    #content-shadow { background: url(images/content-shadow-bg.png) repeat-x top left; padding-top: 70px; padding-bottom: 37px; }   
        #services { margin-bottom: 40px; }
            .service { margin-right: 45px; width: 238px; float:left; position:relative; padding-left: 52px; }
                .last { margin-right: 0px; }
                    img.icon { position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
                    .service h3.title  { font-size: 24px; margin-bottom: 8px; color: #1f262d; }
                    .service p { line-height: 21px; }
                    .service a.readmore { background:url(images/readmore.png) no-repeat right bottom; color:#1c2329; display:block; font-size:11px; height:24px; line-height:24px; padding-right:10px; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ffffff; display:block; float:right; }
                        .service a.readmore span { background:url(images/readmore.png) no-repeat;
display:block; height:24px; padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 2px; }
                        .service a.readmore:hover { color: #000; }
```

Comment: Post a link to the actual blog. Are you saving your changes? How are you editing the CSS file?

Comment: Normally its best to go to Appearance > Theme Options > Design and enter your custom CSS

Comment: Post a link so we can see the blog. There's the possibility that additional stylesheets are being added that might be overwriting your styles.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding

```
h1{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

to your external css file, or substitute your

```
<h1> your text here </h1>
```

with

```
<h1 style="font-weight: bold"> your text here </h1>
```

Comment: Yup, h1{ font-weight: bold; } Works! but `font-weight` with values `100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 to 900 `
doesn't work (probably anymore, it it used to) for heading tags.

Comment: Make some experiments here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font-weight - 

change one of the <p> into <h1> both in body html and in CSS, then change the font size. It seems that the maximum is 600, but lower values still work.

Answer (score 7):

Try CSS font-weight Property Values as:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {

  font-weight:100;

}
```

You can adjust values from `100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 to 900.` The property value as `900` is the thickest and `100` is the lightest.

Comment: It's probably good to mention that many fonts out there do not support all 9 distinct weight values. For `font-weight: bold;`, that is equivalent of using `font-weight: 700`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {

  font-weight:100;
}
```

Your HTML code,

```
<h1> your text here </h1>
<h2> your text here </h2>
<h3> your text here </h3>
<h4> your text here </h4>
<h5> your text here </h5>
<h6> your text here </h6>
```

Code example result,

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {

  font-weight:900;

}
```

```html
<h1> your text here </h1>
<h2> your text here </h2>
<h3> your text here </h3>
<h4> your text here </h4>
<h5> your text here </h5>
<h6> your text here </h6>
```

You can adjust the values from 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 to 900. Property value is 900 as solid and 100 as light.